# Ruby Rspec, Finding how many times a worker being called recursively

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rubygems, rspec-sidekiq

I need to test a worker on Rspec, to Find how many times the same worker being called again and again in recursive manner.
Eg:

```
Class Myworker
  def perform(id)
    model = Mymodel.find(id)
    associated_records = Mymodel.users.limit(1000)
    associated_records.each(&:destroy)
    if Mymodel.users.exists?
      Myworker.perform_async(id)
    end
  end
end
```

i need to write rpsec for this to count how many times this iteration happend,

i have tried to stub the worker, and incrementing counter, since i'm stubbing the worker it doesn't execute the same worker again and i'm struck with counter 1 as final value. How to find how many times the worker being called recursively in RSPEC.

Comment: Why don't you use `find_each` here?

Comment: Counting the number of iterations couples your test to the implementation. Wouldn't it make more sense to check whether all associated users have been destroyed? This way, you can refactor your code (change the limit, remove the recursion) without breaking the test.

Comment: @Stefan What if i have more number of associated user say 10000, each have mulitple destroy call backs, having it in same worker without recursively calling the same worker will make the worker to run long and it will hold the queue for other workers right?

Comment: @jansha you could define a separate low priority queue for long running workers. Or maybe have the worker start a single "DestroyUserWorker" for each user ID. (Sidekick can easily handle 10k jobs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to get in here with a frame challenge: In you specific use case you don't want to call the worker recursively, but you just want to use `find_each` to iteratively remove all the users from `Mymodel`, i.e.

```
Class Myworker
  def perform(id)
    User.where(mymodel_id: id)
        .find_each do |user|
      user.destroy
    end
  end
end
```

**Edit:** If you don't like the idea of deleting all association objects within one run of the worker and definitely want to run your worker recursively, then in my opinion your best option would not be to test the actual amount of recursions for your worker, but rather have two test cases:

1. Test that the worker is rescheduled when there are more association records than you delete in one recursion
2. Test that the worker is not rescheduled when all association records can be deleted within a single iteration

That way you also verify that your worker will run as often as needed to delete all records without the need to verify the actual count of recursions used.

(It's a little bit late at my place and I actually do want to get some sleep, so I'm not putting in example code here, let me know if you need it, I can then add some tomorrow)

Comment: Still if the record count got increases, then the worker may run for long time right?, in order to avoid that we have used to remove the data batch by batch in each worker.
To avoid long running workers
And also the deletion of records will take same time right, using find each will load the data prior and avoid memory issues, but the execution time will be same right? and worker will run for long time and hold , so other workers may be queued until the completion.

Comment: Also MyModel has not only one Association, it have 5 to 6 associated models, and each model may have more than 5000-7000 records. So i have created 6 different workers for each model and on each model i will recursively call the same workers once after once like that.

Answer (score 1):

You are right that when deleting huge amounts of database records, then the job will need more time and ultimately delay other background jobs.

But that should really be an issue because usually you will have multiple workers running at the same time anyway. And when you still have issues with multiple huge jobs delaying more important jobs, then you should think about having multiple queues with different priorities.

When you have [multiple priority queues configured in Sidekiq](https://github.com/sidekiq/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options) then you can change your job to run on a low priority queue and not block the critical or default queue like this:

```
class DestroyUsersAssociatedToMyModel
  include Sidekiq::Job
  sidekiq_options queue: 'low'

  def perform(id)
    MyModel.find(id).users.destroy_all
  end
end
```

Comment: Since removing the user after the mymodel got destroy is a mandatory one and need to be processed in high priority since, we have to remove the user access immediately. so thats why i have planned for recursive approach.

Comment: @spiickermann
Also MyModel has not only one Association, it have 5 to 6 associated models, and each model may have more than 5000-7000 records. So i have created 6 different workers for each model and on each model i will recursively call the same workers once after once like that

Comment: When it is about deleting associated records, then this approach will not work, because `MyModel.find(id)` will already fail when the record was already deleted. Instead, I suggest using Ruby on Rails' build in way to automatically delete associated records. `MyModel has_many :users, dependent: :destroy` or even [`:destroy_async` (see article about this feature)](https://blog.saeloun.com/2020/11/18/rails-6-1-adds-support-for-destroying-dependent-associations-in-the-background/)